# wrting more than one file while autoincrementing file name failed (python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF2 to crop PDF files in a directory. There are 2 of them. My goal is to crop both files and save the new cropped file as "article_0.pdf" and "article_1.pdf":

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
directory=os.getcwd()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    reader = PdfFileReader(file,'r')
writer = PdfFileWriter()
for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
     page = reader.getPage(i)
     page.cropBox.setUpperLeft((0,720))
     page.cropBox.setLowerLeft((0,70))
     page.cropBox.setLowerRight((612,70))
     page.cropBox.setUpperRight((612,720))
     writer.addPage(page)
for index in range(2):
     filename = 'article_%d.pdf'%index
     with open(filename,'wb') as f:
         writer.write(f)
```

The cropping is done properly and the output files are named "article_0.pdf" and "article_1.pdf" as expected. However, both output files are the cropped version of only one of the original files. Why is the cropped version of the other file not in the output files? Thanks!

UPDATE: I tried fixing the indents like this but still got the same results:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
directory=os.getcwd()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    reader = PdfFileReader(file,'r')
    writer = PdfFileWriter()
    for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
        page = reader.getPage(i)
        page.cropBox.setUpperLeft((0,720))
        page.cropBox.setLowerLeft((0,70))
        page.cropBox.setLowerRight((612,70))
        page.cropBox.setUpperRight((612,720))
        writer.addPage(page)
    for index in range(2):
        filename = 'article_%d.pdf'%index
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
             writer.write(f)
```

Comment: You need to indent the lines start from `writer` such that they are within the `for` loop. You also need to update and fix the code starts from `for index` so that it is within the first `for` loop.

Comment: I edited the code according to you suggestions but I still got the same results (see updated post). Can you please check if I did it right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop you're using to write your two files doesn't do anything useful. It *always* writes two files with the same contents, because the contents of `writer` don't change during the loop.

Instead, you should be writing once per iteration of the first loop. To get an index, use `enumerate` to get an index along with the file name when you call `os.listdir`:

```
for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)): # compute index up here with enumerate
    reader = PdfFileReader(file,'r')
    writer = PdfFileWriter()
    for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
        ...
    filename = 'article_%d.pdf' % index              # no extra loop is needed down here
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
         writer.write(f)
```